# jQuery document.ready throws error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am dynamically adding a jQuery multiselect control onto a page like this:

```
 var captionCell = new HtmlTableCell { InnerHtml = control.Caption };
 var inputCell = new HtmlTableCell();
 inputCell.Controls.Add(inputControl);
 var row = new HtmlTableRow();
 row.Cells.Add(captionCell);
 row.Cells.Add(inputCell);
 tbl.Rows.Add(row);
```

And building my javascript string like this:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
 sb.AppendLine("var $callback = $(\"#callback\");");
 sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function () {");
 sb.Append("$(\"#");
 sb.Append(multiSelectControl.ClientID);
 sb.AppendLine("\").multiselect(");
 sb.AppendLine("{");
 sb.AppendLine("show: \"fade\",");
 sb.AppendLine("hide: \"fade\",");
 sb.AppendLine("click: function (event, ui){");
 sb.AppendLine("$callback.text(ui.text + ' ' + (ui.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'));");
 sb.AppendLine("},");
 sb.AppendLine("});");
 sb.AppendLine("});");
 sb.AppendLine("</script>");
```

Then adding the script to the page like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "CreateControl" + inputControl.ClientID,
                            sb.ToString(), false);
```

But im getting the following error when trying to do this:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Please assist guys.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: it seems that you have not added jquery library reference

Comment: sb.AppendLine("},"); it seems an additional comma here...

Comment: Check in console where exactly the error is happening..

Comment: @Mr_Green I've added a screen shot as to where its failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a user control, and when I need to use the script above I just loaded the user control.

Solved everything and works really well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have jQuery included in the page to use document.ready, You did not add the script tag to include jquery in the page, Add script tag to include jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jQueryFolder/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did in the Page_Load event as follows:
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "1", "../../Scripts/jquery/jquery.multiselect.js");

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "2", "../../Scripts/jquery/jquery.ui.js");

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "3", "../../Scripts/jquery/jquery.latest.js");

Comment: @johnnie load jquery.latest first, then jquery ui, then everything else.

Comment: You can simply use script tags instead of using RegisterClientScriptInclude if you do not decide what to include on runtime.

Comment: @KevinB, I rearranged the order in which the files are loaded but it did not work. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var $callback = $("#callback");
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ClientID").multiselect({
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    click: function(event, ui) {
        $callback.text(ui.text + ' ' + (ui.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'));
    }
});
});​
```